# Query GSI from AWS Dynamodb CLI

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

How to query global secondary index (gsi) in dynamodb from aws cli?

I have the following GSI query saved in a gsi.json file

```
{
    "IndexName": {"S": "Index"},
    "KeyConditionExpression": "name = :name",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":name": {"S": "bob"},
        ":id": {"S": "bob-1234"}
    },
    "ProjectionExpression": {"S": "age"},
    "ScanIndexForward": {"BOOL": "false"}
}
```

Now how to run the query using aws dynamodb cli command?